# Calculating with Method of Equal-area differentiation

Tags: biochemistry, kinetics

I have been trying to understand this method although I admit, don’t have a very good calculus background just yet.
For a given reaction where $x$ is time, $f(x)$ is cell concentration and assuming it to be first order (autocatalytic), we obtain the table:
\begin{array}{rrrrr}\hline
x  & 
f(x)  &
\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}  &
\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}  &
\text{actual}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\\\hline
0    &    0    &    -    &    1010    &    1000    \\
0.2  &  182    &    910  &     805    &     818    \\
0.4  &  332    &    740  &     670    &     670    \\
0.6  &  451    &    605  &     550    &     548    \\\hline
\end{array}

For this data: Is it possible to calculate the $\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}x$ column with the rate formula? Or maybe $\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}x$ can only be calculated by using the equal areas given in the plot?

Comment: Could you clarify where you obtained this table? Also, a first order reaction is not the same as an [autocatalytic reaction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocatalysis). Welcome to Chem SE and best of luck getting an answer!

Comment: Hello, and thank you for answering!

I got this method from “elements of chemical reaction engineering” cd-rom manual, available in [link]( http://umich.edu/~elements/appendix/html/CDROM-Appendix-A.pdf). I’ve been investigating more and this method consist on creating a histogram like graph and ‘split each in half’. However, I find this method to be very unreliable and I believe ‘automating it’ a bit with a formula might improve the precision.

Comment: In using this method, whether or not its worthwhile seems to depend a lot on how many points you have. For only a few points, this is a decent approximation scheme, though it requires a bit of judgement on where to draw lines to cut off equal areas. Typically, you will be working with more points and so it might be better to have a method thatch be applied more formulaically.  One method I would suggest with more points is [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient). Alternatively, you can get a decent guess by creating a polynomial or exponential...

Comment: regression line in a spreadsheet or [online calculator](http://www.xuru.org/rt/NLR.asp#CopyPaste) and then differentiating that equation. For this data, I was able to get slopes of 987, 830, 673, and 515 using the best R^2 quadratic curve.